# When and If, Does the 'version' in ContentVersion Change?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, custom-object, contentversion, contentdocument

I'm using the `lightning-file-upload` component to upload files (wow).

My question is: *is it safe to add a custom lookup relationship on the ContentVersion object?*

I guess I don't really understand the 'version' part of the name. Since we have to use `isLatest = true` when we query, does that mean the contentVersion changes on its own and therefore the custom relationship isn't reliable, in the way, that a new version would be created and that record wouldn't have the correct relationship?

Answer (score 1):

It's safe to put a Lookup field on the ContentVersion object, as the Lookup value will automatically be set on a new version from the previous version

If the Lookup value is changed on the latest version, it will only affect the latest version

Comment: Right, do you have somewhere I can read up on that?

Comment: Sorry, don't know of any documentation on it, just answering from experience

Comment: Alright, thank you

Comment: I see this mentions that the data in the custom fields are available "for the life of the file", which I'm guessing means all ContentVersions on the ContentDocument file? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=content_fields.htm&type=5